# NewRelic and Azure Worker Role

Tags: metrics, newrelic, azure-worker-roles

Why is it so difficult to get new relic and azure worker role talking to each other. I have spent frustratingly long hours trying to get custom metrics to work on Azure Role. Here is what I have tried so far

1. Created an Azure Worker Role project Added New Relic x64 for Windows
   Azure & NewRelic.Agent.Api (I don't think the latter is needed)
2. Every 10 seconds, I am publishing a custom metric using the
   following code snippet
   NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.RecordMetric(String.Format("Custom/{0}/queue_length_request", environment.ToLower()), 10);
3. In C:\ProgramData\New Relic.NET Agent\Extensions, I have added a CustomInstrumentation.xml file (attached) with the  contents from the following screenshot
   [image]
4. App.config looks like this (NewRelic.LicenseKey) is added to cloud definition file
   [image]

   I tried executing the project in emulator and also tried deploying to cloud but the custom metrics would not show up. Wondering if there are some steps that I have missed out

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that only the New Relic x64 nuget package is needed.  The API package is only if you want to use the API.

The NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.RecordMetric method creates metrics which are only visible when creating custom dashboards.  They will not be visible as transactions or in transactions traces.

The BackgroundThreadTracerFactory will create a transaction, but under "Custom", in your case, which will be under the Non-web heading in transactions.